# How to automate Citrix Netscaler gateway login using java

Tags: java, netscaler, citrix-access-gateway

I want to automate Citrix(Netscaler Gateway) login using java.

I tried to search and found autologin in gmail, but these 2 tasks are different.

Need some guidance for auto login citrix application(userid,token password, windows password)

Comment: What kind of task you are going to automate, after login? I'm asking since Java is not that funny in automating boring stuff. Anyway - half a year ago there was no open source solution - please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631988/ui-automation-in-citrix)

Comment: just login to citrix automatically by using java code I need.Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've searched for better solution, but only RPAs appears - like [this one](https://www.uipath.com/solutions/technology/citrix-automation).

Answer (score 0):

if you take a look at developer tools the moment you perform a login you will observe that it uses a POST to login